# How to calculate turbojet thrust at variable altitudes and mach numbers?

Tags: jet, thrust

I am interested in developing a flight model in jbsim. jbsim requires a thrust table similar to as follows, with varying mach and altitude numbers (with thrust as a fraction of max):

```
     |  -10000       0   10000   20000   30000   40000   50000
-----+--------------------------------------------------------
0.0  |  1.2600  1.0000  0.7400  0.5340  0.3720  0.2410  0.1490
0.2  |  1.1710  0.9340  0.6970  0.5060  0.3550  0.2310  0.1430
0.4  |  1.1500  0.9210  0.6920  0.5060  0.3570  0.2330  0.1450
0.6  |  1.1810  0.9510  0.7210  0.5320  0.3780  0.2480  0.1540
0.8  |  1.2580  1.0200  0.7820  0.5820  0.4170  0.2750  0.1700
1.0  |  1.3690  1.1200  0.8710  0.6510  0.4750  0.3150  0.1950
1.2  |  1.4850  1.2300  0.9750  0.7440  0.5450  0.3640  0.2250
1.4  |  1.5941  1.3400  1.0860  0.8450  0.6280  0.4240  0.2630
```

Given that I know the thrust of an engine at sea level, in a standard atmosphere at 0 velocity, how would one calculate, or extrapolate the same data for something such as a J57-21?